# Sparse matrix addition in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, sparse-matrix

I'm considering using CUDA C for a particular problem involving sparse matrix addition.

The [docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/#introduction) seem to discuss only operations between a sparse and a dense object.

This leads me to think either: sparse-sparse addition is so trivial it may just be a case of using '+' or similar; or sparse-sparse addition is not implemented. Which is correct, and where can I find the docs?

Comment: The addition of two matrices is a relatively simple operation, regardless of the density of the matrices. As such, you could implement the operation yourself. The only question that remains is what data structure you are using to represent your matrices. Since you mention you are working with sparse matrices, I would suggest the [Compressed Sparse Row (CSR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_row_Storage_.28CRS_or_CSR.29) format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUSPARSE has [some routines](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/#cusparse-extra-function-reference) that can operate on two operands that are both sparse matrices, for addition and multiplication.

You can do sparse matrix - sparse matrix addition with CUSPARSE using the `cusparse<t>csrgeam` [function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrgeam):

> This function performs following matrix-matrix operation
>
> C=α∗A+β∗B
>
> where A, B, and C are m×n sparse matrices (defined in CSR storage format ...

Although dense matrix addition is fairly trivial (could be about 3 lines of code, whether in serial or parallel), I personally would not put sparse addition of two CSR matrices at the same level of triviality, especially if the goal is to perform it in parallel.  You could try writing your own routine; I wouldn't.

Comment: May I ask why the name of the function is `csrgeam`? what is the abbreviation "geam" for?

Answer (score 1):

Sparse-sparse addition is surprisingly tricky unless the matrices are the same sparsity pattern. (If they are, just add the elements of the data vectors and call it a day). You'll probably note that even *calling* the `csrgeam` method takes a couple of steps - one to calculate the size of the resulting matrix, and then another to do the operation. The reason is that the resulting matrix contains the *union* of the two nonzero patterns.

If this wasn't tricky enough, let's talk the parallel case, which you're obviously interested in since you're talking about CUDA. If you're in the CSR format, you could parallelize by rows (something like 1 CUDA thread per matrix row as a first pass). You would want to do a first pass, possibly single-threaded to compute the row pointers and column indices, and then a parallel pass to actually run the computation.

Comment: Cheers. For my use case it would be sufficient to do sparse-sparse addition within a single thread. So one headache, at least spared!

Answer (score 1):

Following Robert Crovella's answer, here is a fully worked example on how summing up two sparse matrices in CUDA:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <cusparse.h>

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
// --- Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { exit(code); }
    }
}

void gpuErrchk(cudaError_t ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/***************************/
/* CUSPARSE ERROR CHECKING */
/***************************/
static const char *_cusparseGetErrorEnum(cusparseStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSPARSE error in file '%s', line %d, error %s\nterminating!\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
            _cusparseGetErrorEnum(err)); \
            assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err) { __cusparseSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseHandle_t handle;    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    // --- Initialize matrix descriptors
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, descrB, descrC;
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrB));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrC));

    const int M = 5;                                    // --- Number of rows
    const int N = 6;                                    // --- Number of columns

    const int nnz1 = 10;                                // --- Number of non-zero blocks for matrix A
    const int nnz2 = 8;                                 // --- Number of non-zero blocks for matrix A

    // --- Host vectors defining the first block-sparse matrix
    float *h_csrValA = (float *)malloc(nnz1 * sizeof(float));
    int *h_csrRowPtrA = (int *)malloc((M + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int *h_csrColIndA = (int *)malloc(nnz1 * sizeof(int));

    // --- Host vectors defining the second block-sparse matrix
    float *h_csrValB = (float *)malloc(nnz1 * sizeof(float));
    int *h_csrRowPtrB = (int *)malloc((M + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int *h_csrColIndB = (int *)malloc(nnz1 * sizeof(int));

    h_csrValA[0] = 1.f;
    h_csrValA[1] = 7.f;
    h_csrValA[2] = 1.f;
    h_csrValA[3] = 3.f;
    h_csrValA[4] = -1.f;
    h_csrValA[5] = 10.f;
    h_csrValA[6] = 1.f;
    h_csrValA[7] = -4.f;
    h_csrValA[8] = 1.f;
    h_csrValA[9] = 3.f;

    h_csrRowPtrA[0] = 0;
    h_csrRowPtrA[1] = 3;
    h_csrRowPtrA[2] = 5;
    h_csrRowPtrA[3] = 6;
    h_csrRowPtrA[4] = 8;
    h_csrRowPtrA[5] = 10;

    h_csrColIndA[0] = 0;
    h_csrColIndA[1] = 3;
    h_csrColIndA[2] = 5;
    h_csrColIndA[3] = 2;
    h_csrColIndA[4] = 4;
    h_csrColIndA[5] = 1;
    h_csrColIndA[6] = 0;
    h_csrColIndA[7] = 3;
    h_csrColIndA[8] = 3;
    h_csrColIndA[9] = 5;

    h_csrValB[0] = 3.f;
    h_csrValB[1] = 1.f;
    h_csrValB[2] = -1.f;
    h_csrValB[3] = 1.f;
    h_csrValB[4] = -4.f;
    h_csrValB[5] = -3.f;
    h_csrValB[6] = -2.f;
    h_csrValB[7] = 10.f;

    h_csrRowPtrB[0] = 0;
    h_csrRowPtrB[1] = 2;
    h_csrRowPtrB[2] = 4;
    h_csrRowPtrB[3] = 5;
    h_csrRowPtrB[4] = 7;
    h_csrRowPtrB[5] = 8;

    h_csrColIndB[0] = 0;
    h_csrColIndB[1] = 4;
    h_csrColIndB[2] = 0;
    h_csrColIndB[3] = 1;
    h_csrColIndB[4] = 3;
    h_csrColIndB[5] = 0;
    h_csrColIndB[6] = 1;
    h_csrColIndB[7] = 3;

    // --- Device vectors defining the block-sparse matrices
    float *d_csrValA;       gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrValA, nnz1 * sizeof(float)));
    int *d_csrRowPtrA;      gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrRowPtrA, (M + 1) * sizeof(int)));
    int *d_csrColIndA;      gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrColIndA, nnz1 * sizeof(int)));

    float *d_csrValB;       gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrValB, nnz2 * sizeof(float)));
    int *d_csrRowPtrB;      gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrRowPtrB, (M + 1) * sizeof(int)));
    int *d_csrColIndB;      gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrColIndB, nnz2 * sizeof(int)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_csrValA, h_csrValA, nnz1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_csrRowPtrA, h_csrRowPtrA, (M + 1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_csrColIndA, h_csrColIndA, nnz1 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_csrValB, h_csrValB, nnz2 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_csrRowPtrB, h_csrRowPtrB, (M + 1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_csrColIndB, h_csrColIndB, nnz2 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Summing the two matrices
    int baseC, nnz3;
    // --- nnzTotalDevHostPtr points to host memory
    int *nnzTotalDevHostPtr = &nnz3;
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetPointerMode(handle, CUSPARSE_POINTER_MODE_HOST));
    int *d_csrRowPtrC;   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrRowPtrC, (M + 1) * sizeof(int)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseXcsrgeamNnz(handle, M, N, descrA, nnz1, d_csrRowPtrA, d_csrColIndA, descrB, nnz2, d_csrRowPtrB, d_csrColIndB, descrC, d_csrRowPtrC, nnzTotalDevHostPtr));
    if (NULL != nnzTotalDevHostPtr) {
        nnz3 = *nnzTotalDevHostPtr;
    }
    else{
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&nnz3, d_csrRowPtrC + M, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&baseC, d_csrRowPtrC, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        nnz3 -= baseC;
    }
    int *d_csrColIndC;   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrColIndC, nnz3 * sizeof(int)));
    float *d_csrValC;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_csrValC, nnz3 * sizeof(float)));
    float alpha = 1.f, beta = 1.f;
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseScsrgeam(handle, M, N, &alpha, descrA, nnz1, d_csrValA, d_csrRowPtrA, d_csrColIndA, &beta, descrB, nnz2, d_csrValB, d_csrRowPtrB, d_csrColIndB, descrC, d_csrValC, d_csrRowPtrC, d_csrColIndC));

    // --- Transforming csr to dense format
    float *d_C;             gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_C, M * N * sizeof(float)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseScsr2dense(handle, M, N, descrC, d_csrValC, d_csrRowPtrC, d_csrColIndC, d_C, M));

    float *h_C = (float *)malloc(M * N * sizeof(float));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, M * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // --- m is row index, n column index
    for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            printf("%f ", h_C[m + n * M]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```